# Relational database design considering partly dependent information?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I strongly having the feeling, I don't see the wood for the trees, so I need your help.

Think of the following two tables:

```
create table Category (Category_ID    integer,
                       Category_Desc  nvarchar2(500));

create table Text (Text_Id       integer,
                   Text          nvarchar2(1000),
                   Category_Id   integer references Category.Category_Id);
```

This code follows no proper syntax, it's just to get an idea of the problem.

Consider the idea to save text parts for certain categories to use them in an interface, like messages ("You can't do that!", "Do this!",...), but also to create notes for other objects, e. g. like orders ("Important customer! Prioritize this order!").

Now for my question. Some of this text bits bring some more information with them, like if you add the "Important customer" note to an order, also the `Order.Prio_Flag` is set.

Now this is a very special information, only considering text used by the category `Order_Note`. I don't want to add this to the `Text` table, since most of the entries are not affected by this and the table would get more and more crowded by special cases for only the least part of its content.

I get the feeling, the design is flawed, but I also don't want a table for every category and keep this as general as possible.

Keep in mind, this is a simplified view of the problem.

**TL:DR:** How do I add information to a table's content without adding new attributes, because the new attribute would only be filled for the least number of entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtyping and dependent attributes are easy to do in a relational database.  For example, if some `Text`s are important and need to have a dependent attribute (e.g. `DisplayColor`), you could add the following table to your schema:

```
CREATE TABLE ImportantText (
    Text_Id integer NOT NULL ,
    Display_Color integer NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (Text_Id),
    CONSTRAINT ImportantTextSubtypeOfText
        FOREIGN KEY (Text_Id) REFERENCES Text (Text_Id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Many people think foreign key constraints establish relationships between entities.  That's not what they're for.  They're CONSTRAINTS, i.e. they limit the values in a column to be a subset of another column.  In this way, a subtyping relation is established which can record additional properties.

In the table above, any element of `ImportantText` must be an element of `Text`, and will have all the attributes of `Text` (since it must be recorded in the `Text` table), as well as the additional attributes of `ImportantText`.

Comment: It's obvious as you mention it. Thanks a lot!